# How to establish SSH tunnel from python script on Google Cloud Run to server with PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database-connection, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-run, ssh-tunnel, vpc

I've done some research and based on it, my first question is:

**It is not possible to establish an SSH tunnel from python script in Google Cloud Run to the server where the database is located natively, right?**

If it is so, then, what workarounds would you suggest? I found a [deprecated solution](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-static-outbound-ip) which is of course no longer intended to be used. The author wrote [a new official guideline](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) on how to approach this problem, but I do not understand in which way it solves it. In the end, we get a static IP address and we just need to whitelist it in our database?

So, please, suggest any other workarounds or comment on something that I missed or do not understand about the mentioned ones.
Thank you!

Comment: Neither link is related to your question. Why do you want to connect from Cloud Run to a database using SSH? Databases do not use the SSH protocol. Edit your post to clarify the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @JohnHanley hi. What I meant is that I need to establish an SSH tunnel between my Cloud Run application and the remote PostgreSQL Database. So I need to connect to the server where the database is located. 
I thought that the first link is related because it does establish an SSH tunnel but to the GCE instance with static IP, which in its turn could be used for accessing the database, only if whitelisted, of course.

Comment: Two steps are required. 1) You will need to configure OpenSSH on the Compute Engine instance to tunnel traffic to PostgreSQL. You do not need a static IP address for Cloud Run, so neither link is relevant. 2) You will need to embed an SSH client in your code to use the SSH tunnel. Once you have configured something and have a problem, post a question with details. Note: you might be able to configure a Cloud Run sidecar to handle the SSH client side, but I have not tried that. Suggestion: unless you understand what this means you have a lot of work to do. Why not use standard methods?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I understood the first part, the second will need more research from me. 
About why I ask specifically about this method - I am just bound to this architecture where I must use Cloud Run on the one side and the remote PostgreSQL Database with SSH connection to it on the other. 
But still, could you please tell, what would be the standard methods for this situation?

Comment: The standard method is to use a PostgreSQL client and connect to the database.

Comment: Oh, that is already done. Sorry that the question is not descriptive enough. Connection is needed to go from the Python script that needs to be deployed to run on a schedule so PostgreSQL client is not suitable. However, we found a solution, that does not require an SSH connection. Thank you for investing your time and explaining all this to me. I believe I should add more details to my question and we can accept your second comment as an answer because although I couldn't implement it, it was still an explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As discussed by @John Hanley

> Two steps are required. 1) You will need to configure OpenSSH on the Compute Engine instance to tunnel traffic to PostgreSQL. You do not need a static IP address for Cloud Run, so neither link is relevant. 2) You will need to embed an SSH client in your code to use the SSH tunnel. Once you have configured something and have a problem, post a question with details. Note: you might be able to configure a Cloud Run sidecar to handle the SSH client side, but I have not tried that. Suggestion: unless you understand what this means you have a lot of work to do. Why not use standard methods?